# After uploading photos to Facebook from Aperture, all I see is "There are no photos in this album."

Tags: facebook, photos, upload, photo-sharing

I'm using Apple's [Aperture](http://www.apple.com/aperture/) to manage photos on my laptop. It has a built-in "share to Facebook" feature, which allows me to create a Facebook album and upload photos into it.

### The procedure

- When I create an album from a set of photos, I can choose "Everyone", "Friends of Friends", or "Only Friends" for the privacy settings. I've been choosing "**Friends of Friends**".
- **The photos take several minutes to upload.** It's clear that the photos *are* actually being uploaded somewhere.
- The activity indicator **correctly shows when I most recently added a photo** via Aperture: [image] (and this timestamp updates if I add another photo to the album from within Aperture).

### The problem

When I view my list of photo albums, I only see this:

[image]

and when I open the album:

[image]

**Is there something I need to do to make Facebook recognize the photos that have been uploaded?** (Is this a problem with Facebook, or is it an Aperture problem and I should be looking for solutions elsewhere?)

*(Note: I've successfully used Aperture's Facebook integration before — and I don't believe anything about my configuration has changed since then.)*

Comment: Have you tried removing and re-authorizing the app on Facebook yet? Also, are you using the most up to date version of Aperture? I ask because I've had so many issues with Facebook app code getting updated but my install broke because some things like permissions access changed.

Comment: @Dez I am using the most recent version of Aperture. When I click on "via Aperture" on other photos I've uploaded, it takes me to [an error page](https://www.facebook.com/apps/application.php?id=101622214608) as if the app doesn't exist.

Comment: That last part is because Aperture doesn't have a canvas (apps.facebook.com/something) or website app defined in their app settings, it's the desktop client - it shouldn't be related to your problem - try removing the app from your privacy settings, re-adding it via arperture's settings page